# Check if stdout is attached to a terminal from an AWK script

Tags: awk, stdout

Is there any way I can check if an AWK script's stdout is attached to a terminal, just like `test -t 1` in a shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your awk has the `system()` function which can run commands:

```
awk 'BEGIN{rc = system("test -t 1")}'
```

`rc` will be the return code of the test.